# magento2 catalogsearch block override layer

Tags: magento2

How to override my custom catalogsearch block?
and what is the equivalent class for below in magento2? and how to override in di?

```
   <catalogsearch>
      <rewrite>
        <layer>Vendor_Module_Block_CatalogSearch_Layer</layer>
      </rewrite>
    </catalogsearch>
```

My custom catalosearch override is as:

```
 <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogSearch\Layer" />
```

is that correct class?
cause in magento1x , we do by

**class Vendor_Module_Block_CatalogSearch_Layer extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer {}**

But in magento2, thr is no such Layer in CatalogSearch.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation**

1. In this class the layer object `getLayer` returns
       **\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer**.
2. Also you can find some important layered navigation functions at
   **Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer`and`Layer.php**.
3. You may not find ( Magento 1.X )exact or entire class in Magento 2
   but we can identify the flow  to customize or extend the functionality by using modules.

Assume you know how to extend or override core classes in Magento 2 ( Standard way is by creating custom module )

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi @krishna, need suggestion on this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138618/correct-class-for-overridding-custom-product-collection-on-search-magento-2